# Law of total probability giving contradictory results

Tags: probability

> An insurance company has two types of users, $A$ and $B$. The number of the two types of users is the same. The former has probability $a$ of causing a car accident this year, the latter $b$. This probability is independent from the previous years. A user is chosen at random. What's the probability that the user has a car accident in two consecutive years?

Let $I_i$ be the event "the user is involved in a car accident in the $i$-th year". Let the current year be the year one. We want to calculate $p = P(I_1 \cap I_2)$. I get contradictory results, depending on when I apply the law of total probability.

1) Since $I_1$ and $I_2$ are indepentent,
$$\begin{align*}
p &= P(I_1) P(I_2) =\\
&= (P(I_1 \mid A)P(A) + P(I_1 \mid B)P(B))(P(I_2 \mid A)P(A) + P(I_2 \mid B)P(B)) =\\
&= \frac12{(a + b)}^2
\end{align*}$$

2) Alternatively,
$$p = P(I_1 \cap I_2 \mid A)P(A) + P(I_1 \cap I_2 \mid B)P(B) = \frac12(a^2 + b^2)$$

The two answer differ by an addend of $ab$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first computation, you pick a user in year one, and then randomly pick another user in year two, which is not what the question is asking. Your second computation is correct because you pick one user, and look at both years for that user.

In particular, the events $I_1$ and $I_2$ are not independent. What is independent is $I_1 \mid A$ and $I_2 \mid A$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot for explaining the fault in my reasoning.